# Creating a fake has_many relationship - one that depends on some other member var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

My application has a user model with some simple access level checks.  This access level determines the scope of access to the other models in the database.  To be precise, I have District, School, Teacher, Room and Student models.  An Admin can see all records, a District can see all child schools, teachers, rooms and students, a principal can see all child teachers, rooms and students, a teacher can see all child rooms and students.

This is done by associating a User object with one or more levels of models.

```
belongs_to :district
belongs_to :school
belongs_to :teacher
```

So a school principal would have a district id and a school id, but its teacher id would be null.

Access to the children is controlled via functions like this:

```
def teachers
    if is_admin?
        Teacher.all
    elsif is_district_head?
        district.teachers
    elsif is_principal?
        school.teachers
    else
        [ teacher ]
    end
end
```

This func is treated in code as if it were a plain old has_many relationship, where we can do stuff like:

```
current_user.teachers.find param[:teacher_id]
current_user.teachers.each {|t| puts t.id }
```

Whether the current_user is an admin or a teacher or anything in between, the correct amount of teachers is returned.

Except, that's sadly not the case.  Only the actual has_many relationships work fully, my fake ones fail when I try to use .find or some function that's specific to the ActiveRecord collections created by has_many.

So, on to my question.  How can I return an ActiveRecord collection object without explicitly calling the has_many function?

If you think I'm a bleedin' retard and I'm missing something godawfully obvious, please don't hesitate to enlighten me!  I had thought this system was going great, until I had to use a .find off an administrator level user account.  It was essentially running

```
Teacher.all.find :conditions => 'xyz'
```

...and that sadly returns an Enumerator object instead of an ActiveRecord for the Teacher model.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have four roles (Admin, District Head, Principal, and Teacher(?)). Each user has one of these roles, and you have a set of rules to determine the access privileges for each role. Correct?

This problem has been solved. I would urge you to consider an authorization system such as CanCan or Declarative Authorization. Both contain straightforward ways to handle the issues you are struggling with here. There's a learning curve, or course, but the time will be well spent.

Comment: CanCan looks excellent, but it doesn't quite fit what I'm after here.  The reason I've organised the models this way is because I have to.  The heirarchy of district, school, teacher, room and student is essential to what I need to do with the data, and the User model must be able to be 'attached' to any level (above class, at least)

edit: After-thought: and anyways, I wanna know if it's possible to fake ActiveRecord collections.